# How to WRITE DECLARATION for function with only one array as first parameter or spread of elements

Tags: typescript

Consider this function from [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge)

```
smart(...configuration | [...configuration])
```

It can accept one and only one `Configuration[]` or `...args: Configuration[]` and returns `Configuration`.

What type does this function have?

---

***UPDATE:***

I want to make typings for webpack-merge.

This is what I have so far...

```
declare module 'webpack-merge' {

  import { Configuration } from 'webpack'

  type StrategyType = 'prepend' | 'append' | 'replace'
  type StrategyMap = { [feild: string]: StrategyType }
  type ConfigurationFolder = (
    conf?: Configuration[], 
    ...args: Configuration[]) => Configuration

  export const merge: ConfigurationFolder
  export const multiple: ConfigurationFolder
  export const smart: ConfigurationFolder

  export const smartStrategy: (options: StrategyMap) => ConfigurationFolder
  export const unique: ConfigurationFolder

  export default merge
}
```

...but it doesnt work as expected.

Here is the test:

```
import * as webpackMerge from 'webpack-merge'

const webpackConfig = webpackMerge.smartStrategy({ entry: 'replace' })(
    configs,
    baseConfig 
    # must fail here: only one `Configuration[]` as first param,
    # or only `Configuration, Configuration, Configuration, ....`
  )
```

---

***UPDATE2***

What I want:

```
class Configuration { }
type Func = (...configuration: Configuration[]) => Configuration;

// usage
const myFunc: Func = (...configuration: Configuration[]) => {
  return new Configuration();
}

const conf = new Configuration;
const confs = [conf];

const r1 = myFunc(confs); // right
const r2 = myFunc(conf); // right
const r3 = myFunc(conf, conf); // right

const f1 = myFunc(confs, confs); // must fail, cause can accept only one array
const f2 = myFunc(conf, confs); // must fail, cause or array, or spread
const f3 = myFunc(confs, conf); // must fail, same
```

[Here is a playable version of what I want.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Configuration%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Func%20%3D%20(...configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20Configuration%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20usage%0D%0Aconst%20myFunc%3A%20Func%20%3D%20(...configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Configuration()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conf%20%3D%20new%20Configuration%3B%0D%0Aconst%20confs%20%3D%20%5Bconf%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r1%20%3D%20myFunc(confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r2%20%3D%20myFunc(conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r3%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20can%20accept%20only%20one%20array%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20or%20array%2C%20or%20spread%0D%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same)

[***UPDATE3***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Configuration%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20context%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20entry%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20output%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Output%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20WasSpead%2C%0D%0A%20%20WasOneArray%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20myFunc(...configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Output%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20myFunc(configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Output%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20usage%0D%0A%2F%2F%20TODO%3A%20body%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conf%20%3D%20new%20Configuration%3B%0D%0Aconst%20confs%20%3D%20%5Bconf%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r1%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r2%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r3%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconsole.log(r1%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasOneArray%2C%20r2%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasSpead%2C%20r3%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasSpead)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f1%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20can%20accept%20only%20one%20array%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f2%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20or%20array%2C%20or%20spread%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f3%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f4%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(%22%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same)

[spin-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908914/how-to-write-body-for-function-with-only-one-array-as-first-parameter-or-spread)

Comment: Didn't understand. What do you want to do?

Comment: @PronoyMukherjee Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) to describe a function that...

> can accept one and only one `Configuration[]` or `...args: Configuration[]` and returns `Configuration`

Here is the declaration.

```
declare function smart(...configuration: Configuration[]): Configuration;
declare function smart(configuration: Configuration[]): Configuration;
```

Here is [an example of its usage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20in%20your%20declaration%20file...%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20Configuration%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20public%20context%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20entry%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20output%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20myFunc(...configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Configuration%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20myFunc(configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Configuration%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20in%20the%20module%20consumer's%20file...%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conf%20%3D%20new%20Configuration()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20confs%20%3D%20%5Bconf%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r1%20%3D%20myFunc(confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r2%20%3D%20myFunc(conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r3%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20f1%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20can%20accept%20only%20one%20array%0D%0Aconst%20f2%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20or%20array%2C%20or%20spread%0D%0Aconst%20f3%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same).

```
// in the module's *.d.ts declaration file...

declare class Configuration { 
  public context: any;
  public entry: any;
  public output: any;
}

declare function myFunc(...configuration: Configuration[]): Configuration;
declare function myFunc(configuration: Configuration[]): Configuration;

// in the module consumer's *.ts file...

const conf = new Configuration();
const confs = [conf];

const r1 = myFunc(confs); // right
const r2 = myFunc(conf); // right
const r3 = myFunc(conf, conf); // right

const f1 = myFunc(confs, confs); // must fail, cause can accept only one array
const f2 = myFunc(conf, confs); // must fail, cause or array, or spread
const f3 = myFunc(confs, conf); // must fail, same
```

Comment: @bjornmelgaard It's hard to understand, because the actual signature of the `merge.smart` function accepts an object: https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge/blob/6bf19b6eb376774beb8ff70a392a956eb7455da6/src/index.js#L34

Comment: no, it accepts `(...configuration | [...configuration])` https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge#smart-merging

Comment: @bjornmelgaard Thank you for clarifying. Does the update to the answer work for you?

Comment: @bjornmelgaard I think function overloading my work for your situation.

Comment: mmm, looks awesome, can you show how to make function body, look UPDATE3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152961/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-bjornmelgaard).