# How to WRITE BODY for function with only one array as first parameter or spread of elements

Tags: typescript

this is spin-off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908043/how-to-describe-function-with-only-one-array-as-first-parameter-or-spread-of-ele#45908043)

I want to write function body that will preserve all properties of this declaration

```
declare function myFunc(...configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
declare function myFunc(configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
```

That's where we left off with @shaun-luttin

```
class Configuration {
  public context: any;
  public entry: any;
  public output: any;
}

enum Output {
  WasSpead,
  WasOneArray
}

function myFunc(...configuration: Configuration[]): Output { 
  return Output.WasSpead
};
function myFunc(configuration: Configuration[]): Output {
  return Output.WasOneArray
};

const conf = new Configuration;
const confs = [conf];

const r1: Output = myFunc(confs); // right
const r2: Output = myFunc(conf); // right
const r3: Output = myFunc(conf, conf); // right
console.log(r1 === Output.WasOneArray, r2 === Output.WasSpead, r3 === Output.WasSpead)

//const f1: Output = myFunc(confs, confs); // must fail, cause can accept only one array
//const f2: Output = myFunc(conf, confs); // must fail, cause or array, or spread
//const f3: Output = myFunc(confs, conf); // must fail, same
//const f4: Output = myFunc(""); // must fail, wtf
```

[Playable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Configuration%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20context%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20entry%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20output%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20Output%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20WasSpead%2C%0D%0A%20%20WasOneArray%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunc(...configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Output%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20Output.WasSpead%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20myFunc(configuration%3A%20Configuration%5B%5D)%3A%20Output%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20Output.WasOneArray%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20conf%20%3D%20new%20Configuration%3B%0D%0Aconst%20confs%20%3D%20%5Bconf%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r1%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r2%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconst%20r3%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20right%0D%0Aconsole.log(r1%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasOneArray%2C%20r2%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasSpead%2C%20r3%20%3D%3D%3D%20Output.WasSpead)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f1%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20can%20accept%20only%20one%20array%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f2%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(conf%2C%20confs)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20cause%20or%20array%2C%20or%20spread%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f3%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(confs%2C%20conf)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20f4%3A%20Output%20%3D%20myFunc(%22%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20must%20fail%2C%20same)

UPDATE (my impl)

```
function myFunc(...configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
function myFunc(configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
function myFunc(...configuration): Output {
  if (Array.isArray(configuration[0])) return Output.WasOneArray
  return Output.WasSpead
};
```

UPDATE2

same through interface

neat if you have multiple functions that has same type, and it would be really neat to just define them as const and set same type

```
class Configuration {
  public context: any;
  public entry: any;
  public output: any;
}

enum Output {
  WasSpead,
  WasOneArray
}


interface Outputter {
  (...configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
  (configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
}

const myFunc: Outputter = (...configuration) => {
  if (Array.isArray(configuration[0])) return Output.WasOneArray
  return Output.WasSpead
}

const myFuncDeceiver: Outputter = (...configuration) => {
  if (Array.isArray(configuration[0])) return Output.WasSpead
  return Output.WasOneArray
}

const conf = new Configuration;
const confs = [conf];

const r1: Output = myFunc(confs); // right
const r2: Output = myFunc(conf); // right
const r3: Output = myFunc(conf, conf); // right
console.log(r1 === Output.WasOneArray, r2 === Output.WasSpead, r3 === Output.WasSpead)

//const f1: Output = myFunc(confs, confs); // must fail, cause can accept only one array
//const f2: Output = myFunc(conf, confs); // must fail, cause or array, or spread
//const f3: Output = myFunc(confs, conf); // must fail, same
//const f4: Output = myFunc(""); // must fail, same
```

Comment: Note that your test for `enum Output { WasSpead, WasOneArray }` is not accurate. We will not be able to differentiate spread arguments from array arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to WRITE BODY for function with only one array as first parameter or spread of elements.

#### Function Overloading

We can use function overloading for that. The trick is to define the function overload signatures separately from the function body.

```
class Configuration {
  public context: any;
  public entry: any;
  public output: any;
}

enum Output {
    WasOneItem, 
    WasMultipleItems,
}

function myFunc(...configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
function myFunc(configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
function myFunc(...configuration) 
{
    if (configuration.length) {
        return Output.WasMultipleItems;
    }

    return Output.WasOneItem;
};
```

**Note:** we can determine whether the input was one or multiple items, but we *cannot* determine whether it was input through an array or a spread.

#### Function Type Interfaces

As you have rightfully noted, we can also use interfaces and arrow functions for this.

```
interface Func { 
     (...configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
    (configuration: Configuration[]): Output;
}

const myFunc: Func = (...configuration) => { 
    if (configuration.length) {
        return Output.WasMultipleItems;
    }

    return Output.WasOneItem;
}
```

Comment: eee, awesome, I have updated with my implementation too)) thank you kind sir)

Comment: one more question, how to make the same but through type?)) like this

Comment: @bjornmelgaard That's where the function interface augmentations come in handy.

Comment: the only downside with `Function Type Interfaces` is that autocompleter shows that myFunc is constant, thought it is function